# Installation program on a network share

Tags: installation

I have a freeware software, which i want to install on a network share. The reason is, if the software is installed on a network share, all users which has access to this network share folder should be able to use the program.

Now, I run the setup.exe on my machine and choose on the step "destination installation" my network share \sharename\TestFolder.
The software was installaing on this sharefolder and after the installation it was possible to run the program on my computer without any errors and use it..

After that I try to start the program on other client but there is always an error message, that it starts with a false operator.

Now my question is, is there a software, which can observe on which files the program want to access when I make double click on the  (program.EXE).

Thank you, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several tools that can monitor or observe system changes performed by a setup.exe.

Many of these tools are quite old and may not operate correctly in new versions of Windows. The most recent one I found that looks acceptable was [EMCO MSI Package Builder](http://emcosoftware.com/msi-package-builder). I never tested the monitor feature, but it is at least an updated capture product.

In my experience these monitor tools capture way too much low-level system stuff, and you will need to spend quite a bit of time to sort out what is really needed for the software to operate. If you have experience with software development you may get just as much information from using a System Internals tool such as RegMon, FileMon or ProcMon. See Microsoft site: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx . These tools are exceptionally useful and known for their small size and great feature set. You can run a ProcMon on the launch of the application executable.

It is also possible that the setup.exe is a wrapper for an MSI file. These files can be viewed with free tools such as Orca and EMCO MSI Package Builder and you can basically see what registration settings are needed for the application to operate. Try opening a command prompt and write setup.exe /a and see if it offers to create an "administrative installation point" - or similar.

If I were to guess I'd say that the software needs to have COM servers registered locally, registry keys added to each local computer and possibly you need to install a couple of runtimes on each system - for example Microsoft C runtime of a particular version. This is just a wild guess. What is the name of the software? If it is a .NET application you may need assemblies installed to the Global Assembly Cache GAC.